Volvo V70: Power windows work differently after power outage
My Volvo recently had a generator issue that caused it to drain its battery completely (as in: not even power to the dashboard). After having a garage replace the generator and test and charge the battery, things are back to normal - almost.
The power windows have that sort of two-step switches that allow you to roll down the window for a bit while you're activating the button, or you can lift/depress the button entirely and the window will go fully up/down. It's this latter feature that no longer functions. Is there anything I can do to fix this that doesn't involve a costly trip to a garage?
I've previously had problems with the automatic start/stop function which was resolved by switching to a better battery. This feature still works so I'm guessing the battery is okay and it's perhaps a configuration issue that I don't have a user interface for. There are user settings for "triple indicator" and "turning headlights" but obviously a ton of features don't have (user facing) configurable settings.

From the V70 online user manual:

Resetting
If the battery is disconnected then the function for automatic opening
must be reset so that it can work correctly.

Gently raise the front section of the button to raise the window to its end position and hold it there for one second.

Release the button briefly.

Raise the front section of the button again for one second.




Amazing, this worked a charm. Thank you!
